# Dynamically load script from Angular service using Angular 14

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm, trying to dynamically append a script from inside my service that i've created,
but i'm getting the following error in the browser:

[image]

Here is the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HotjarService {

  constructor() { }

  loadHotjar(): void {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true;
    script.src = `https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-${environment.hotjar.id}.js?sv=${environment.hotjar.version}`;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    script.onload = () => {
      console.log('loaded successfully');
    };
  }
}
```

I'm runing the `loadHotjar` method from the app component like this:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.hotJarService.loadHotjar();
  }
```

Any help with this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Are the variables from your environment (hotjar id and version) defined and correctly passed to the script src?

Comment: As far as I read the [setup guide](https://help.hotjar.com/hc/en-us/articles/115009336727-How-to-Install-Your-Hotjar-Tracking-Code#manually) this is not the correct way to integrate the tool. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JSONDerulo yeah, but i need it to use the variables from the environment files.

Comment: You should use a Promise so that you can ensure loading has finished before running code that depends on the script. `const promise = new Promise(resolve => script.onload = resolve); document.head.appendChild(script); return promise;`

Comment: generally, using angular cli,  the "environment.ts" and "environment.prod.ts" are place in the directory "src/environments". At the same level than app like show the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/build#using-environment-specific-variables-in-your-app) Are you sure you're looking for your enviroment from the correct place?

Comment: In the script from the docs they are additionally setting some configuration on the window and document. This part is missing. That could be the reason why it's not working.

Comment: @Eliseo yes i'm sure

Comment: @Anna, try execute first `script.onLoad()=>..`and after the `script.src=..`